# how to get much faster update in offline map using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want a faster update in my google offline Map. I have flickering issue while loading the offline Map. I use some "Z-index" method to avoid the flickering. Any other suggestion for faster update and avoid the flickering on every time map loading.

```
function jsCallFn(msg){
    if(current_canvas=='map-canvas'){
        current_canvas= 'map-canvas2';
    }else{
        current_canvas= 'map-canvas';
    }
    initialize(msg);

    setTimeout(function() {
        if(current_canvas=='map-canvas'){
            $('#map-canvas').css('z-index','999');
            $('#map-canvas2').css('z-index','1');
        }else{
            $('#map-canvas2').css('z-index','999');
            $('#map-canvas').css('z-index','1');
        }
    }, 300);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mapTypeIds = [];
        for (var type in google.maps.MapTypeId) {
            }

            mapTypeIds.push("GoogleRoadMaps");


           //Load Map of Zoom level 17,Whose centre is Current vehicle latitude and longitude
           map = new google.maps.Map(element, {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(maplat,maplng),
                zoom: 17,
                mapTypeId: "GoogleRoadMaps",
                mapTypeControlOptions: {
                    mapTypeIds: mapTypeIds
                }
            });

            //load the tiles in the Map from the server
            map.mapTypes.set("GoogleRoadMaps", new google.maps.ImageMapType({
                getTileUrl: function (coord, zoom) {


                    return "http://127.0.0.1:8081/Map/"+ coord.x + "/" + coord.y + ".png";

                },
                tileSize: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
                name: "GoogleRoadMaps",
                maxZoom: 17
            }));

          //Display marker corresponding to first vehicle  
          var marker1=new google.maps.Marker({
          position: new google.maps.LatLng(latOne,lngOne),
          icon: iconOne

          })

            marker1.setMap(map);//marker1 is mapped into map element
            //Click event on marker1 corresponding to 1st Car
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {

                var actionJsonObj = "{ " + "\"method\":\"Marker1\"" + "\," + "\"params\":\""+obj.v2x[1].CarID +"\" }";//Json string for update the sidebar in java

                    JsHandler.jsFnCall(actionJsonObj);//Call to Javascript to Java interface
                });
                //above is my code for map updation
```

Comment: Be a chap and add some description to it why this works and what it even does.